# Comparison of different IRFs from the VAR model (meta-analysis)

Tags: data-transformation, descriptive-statistics, meta-analysis, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

In my meta-analytic research, I have collected IRFs from papers where two variables x and y are both in log-levels (these variables were entered into some VAR model in this way). In addition, I also have collected IRFs from papers where both variables x and y are in growth rates (in this transformation entered the VAR model). I would like (in a meta-analysis) to analyze these articles together (regressions etc.). Is it correct to take the values from the IRFs where the underlying variables are in growth rates and sum these values for each horizon (e.g. the 8th horizon would be the sum of the 1-8 horizons) and then consider this as the IRFs in log-levels?

I think this is nonsense, because for something like this I would need to know the values of the original variables, whereas I only know the outputs of the underlying articles in the form of IRFs.

Something like that, however, does the highly cited article here in appendix: [https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/scpwps/ecb.wp2584~004629c8e7.en.pdf](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/scpwps/ecb.wp2584%7E004629c8e7.en.pdf)

Could someone help me with this issue? Is it possible to do it this simply or is it nonsense?